Cayley Hamilton Theorem application explanation.
Question : Find the $n$-th power of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ -3 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$$
I found eigenvalues $\lambda = -2 ,-2$.
Then, I followed instructions as provided on this paper:
Some Applications of Cayley Hamilton Theorem
Systems of linear equations:
$$f(\lambda_1) = a_0 + a_1\lambda_1$$.
$$f(\lambda_2) = a_0 + a_1\lambda_2$$
Thus
$$(-2)^n = a_0 + a_1(-2)$$
Differentiating w.r.t.  $\lambda_1$ gives
$$n(\lambda_1)^{(n-1)} = a_1$$
Thus $$a_1 = n(-2)^{n-1}$$
Solving the equation
$ A^n = a_0 + a_1 A$
Gives:
$$A^n = (-2)^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix} 3n-2 & 3n \\ -3n & -3n -2\end{bmatrix}$$
which is the correct answer.
Please explain in detail how the system of linear equations described in the paper are derived.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please read "How to ask a good question": https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992
Your question should be focused to one and only one question. If it isn't your question might be closed and downvoted.

Since the eigenvalues are $-2,-2$ then the characteristic polynomial is $(x+2)^2$ and by Cayley-Hamilton then $(A+2I)^2=0\iff A^2=-4A-4I$
Since $A^2$ is a linear combination of $A$ and $I$ it will ensue that any power of $A$ will also be a linear combination of $A$ and $I$.
You can write $A^n=a_nA+b_nI$ with $\begin{cases}a_0=0,\ b_0=1\\a_1=1,\ b_1=0\end{cases}$
From $A^{n+1}=(a_nA+b_nI)A=a_nA^2+b_nA=a_n(-4A-4I)+b_nA\\=(b_n-4a_n)A-4a_nI$
Then $\begin{cases}a_{n+1}=b_n-4a_n\\b_{n+1}=-4a_n\end{cases}$
Isolating $a_n$ gives $a_{n+2}=-4a_n-4a_{n+1}$ which solves to $a_n=(\alpha n+\beta)(-2)^n$
Initial conditions gives $\beta=0,\ \alpha=-\frac 12$

Therefore $a_n=-\frac n2 (-2)^n$ and $b_n=(1-n)(-2)^n$

The result power is in matrix form $A^n=(-2)^n\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{3n-2}2&-\frac {3n}2\\\frac {3n}2&\frac{3n+2}2\end{pmatrix}$
